# Render DjangoCKEditor in React CKEditor

Tags: reactjs, django, react-native, django-forms, ckeditor

I would like to know whether it is possible to render **RichTextField** from Django CKEditor using CKEditor from *ckeditor5-react* ? As far as I know, we could manually render django field in anyway as long as the **name** and **id** is the same as the form field. But I have no idea how do I replicate Django CKEditor using React CKEditor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to use Django CKEditor with Ckeditor5-react. I have done it in the past and it was doable, but I don't recommend using CKeditor with React anymore. The problem with React Ckeditor is that it stores data in HTML format, meaning you have to "dangerously render HTML" in your react virtual dom. There are many libraries that stores data in a JSON format rather than HTML format like CKEditor do, to name some:

- [Slate Js](http://slatejs.org/)
- [Quill](https://quilljs.com/)
- [Draft Js](https://draftjs.org/)

try using them, you can use TextField in Django Model to store your stringified JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, considering the dangeraous of it, I will consider using those alternatives.